# Base64 string ↔ float array

Tags: array, rust, serialization, floating-point, base64

I need to convert `f32` arrays with a fix length to base64 representation and back.

My current code looks like this. It works, but it feels way too complicated.

How can I improve it?

`main.rs`:

```
extern crate base64;

fn read_float_vec_from_byte_vec(v: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Vec<f32>, String> {
    match v.len() % 4 {
        0 => {
            use std::ptr;
            let p = v.as_ptr();
            let dest_len = v.len() / 4;
            let mut result = Vec::<f32>::with_capacity(dest_len);
            for i in 0..dest_len as isize {
                unsafe {
                    let f_ptr = p.offset(4 * i) as *const f32;
                    result.push(ptr::read::<f32>(f_ptr));
                }
            }
            Ok(result)
        }
        _ => Err("Number of bytes not divisible by 4.".to_string())
    }
}

fn float_vec_as_byte_vec(values: &Vec<f32>) -> Vec<u8> {
    let dest_len = values.len() * 4;
    let mut result = Vec::<u8>::with_capacity(dest_len);
    result.resize(dest_len, 0);
    for (i, x) in values.iter().enumerate() {
        let bytes: [u8; 4] = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(*x) };
        result[i*4..i*4+4].copy_from_slice(&bytes[..]);
    }
    result
}

fn show_base64_decode_error(e: base64::DecodeError) -> String {
    use std::error::Error;
    format!("{:?}", e.description())
}

fn base64_to_f32_16_array(base64_str: &str) -> Result<[f32; 16], String>
{
    base64::decode(base64_str
        ).map_err(show_base64_decode_error
        ).and_then(read_float_vec_from_byte_vec
        ).map(
        |float_vec| {
            let mut result: [f32; 16] = [0.0; 16];
            result.copy_from_slice(&float_vec[..]);
            result
        }
    )
}

fn f32_16_array_to_base64(vals: &[f32; 16]) -> String
{
    base64::encode(&float_vec_as_byte_vec(&vals.to_vec()))
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    static VALUES: [f32; 16] = [-0.35, -0.97, 0.05, 0.49, 1.35, 1.08, -0.71, 0.27, -0.44, 0.22, -1.34, -1.17, 0.68, 0.02, -0.52, 0.83];
    static BASE64_STR: &str = "MzOzvuxReL/NzEw9SOH6Ps3MrD9xPYo/j8I1v3E9ij6uR+G+rkdhPh+Fq7+PwpW/exQuPwrXozy4HgW/4XpUPw==";
    #[test]
    fn base64_to_f32_16_array_test() {
        assert_eq!(super::base64_to_f32_16_array(&BASE64_STR), Ok(VALUES));
        assert_eq!(
            super::base64_to_f32_16_array("foo"),
            Err("Number of bytes not divisible by 4.".to_string()));
    }
    #[test]
    fn f32_16_array_to_base64_test() {
        assert_eq!(super::f32_16_array_to_base64(&VALUES), BASE64_STR);
    }
}
```

`cargo.toml` (for completeness):

```
[package]
name = "base64_f32_test"
version = "0.1.0"

[dependencies]
base64 = "0.9.0"
```

Comment: Not enough content for a full answer, but can't the first `match` just be an `if`?

Comment: @Challenger5 Yes, I guess it can. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use iterators: when you use a line like this `for i in 0..dest_len as isize`, the compiler cannot optimize when going through the slice.

A better example:

```
fn read_float_vec_from_byte_vec(v: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Vec<f32>, &'static str> {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn float_from_u8_slice(s: &[u8]) -> f32 {
        let array = [s[0], s[1], s[2], s[3]];
        unsafe { std::mem::transmute(array) }
    }

    match v.len() % 4 {
        0 => Ok(v.chunks(4).map(float_from_u8_slice).collect()),
        _ => Err("Number not divisible by 4"),
    }
}
```

With the iteration over `v.chunks(4).map(float_from_u8_slice).collect()`, the code is smaller and more readable. Generally speaking, iterators are always better than indexing because indexing operation performs bounds checks.

Unfortunately, you cannot do the same with `float_vec_as_byte_vec` because (for now) arrays in Rust are not a first-class citizen. Due to the fact that genericity on integers does not exist, you cannot consume an array into an iterator. If it did, we could write something like:

```
// This code does not work currently
fn float_vec_as_byte_vec(s: &[f32]) -> Vec<u8> {
    s.iter().flat_map(|&f| unsafe { transmute::<f32, [u8; 4]>(f)).collect()
}
```

In this code, I accept the type `&[f32]`, instead of `&Vec<f32>`. Slices are a view of memory, and that is what we want. `&Vec<f32>` does not really make sense, semantically.

In the first function I rewrote, I used `&'static str` and not `String` because we do not need an allocated string since it is literal.

Comment: This looks better, thanks a lot.

Just as a remark: Simply replacing `read_float_vec_from_byte_vec` with your version [like this](https://ideone.com/jobtX1) results in an error in line 36 (`expected reference, found struct std::string::String`).

However, changing your function signature to `fn read_float_vec_from_byte_vec(v: Vec<u8>) -> Result<Vec<f32>, String> {` and [adding `to_string` in the right place](https://ideone.com/d7GuR7) makes it work. :)

Comment: Oh, and clippy does not like the call to `transmute` and gives the following warning: [transmute from `[u8; 4]` to a less-aligned type (`f32`)](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-clippy/v0.0.185/index.html#misaligned_transmute)

Comment: @TobiasHermann Sure, that's because you need a `String` after that. This modification was kind of generic and I did not took into account your particular usage after that.

Comment: @TobiasHermann the lint is buggy and wrong in this case (see https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy/pull/2400#issuecomment-361609289)

Comment: "the compiler cannot optimize" - why not? It certainly may be able to see all indexes in range looped over are valid (I'm not saying there aren't other good reasons to use iterators).

Comment: @Stefan In this specific case, iteration is not (to be checked) faster because there are no indexing. I updated my answer.